HPC remote server side rsync command limit
I am currently trying to transfer three different files (that have multiple versions) to directories on a computing cluster via SSH using  the rsync command. Two of these files exist in the same local directory, and are transferred in a single rsync command, however, the last files are found in a different directory and require a separate use of rsync. After running the script, it will successfully transfer many of the files, but reliably exits after 5-6 directories with the following errors:
````
ssh: connect to host owlsnest.hpc.temple.edu port 22: Connection refused
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(231) [sender=3.2.7]

```

The relevant code is below:
scriptdir="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"
basedir="$(dirname "$scriptdir")"

fmriprep_dir=/ZPOOL/data/projects/rf1-sra-data/derivatives/fmriprep
bids_dir=/ZPOOL/data/projects/rf1-datapaper-dev/bids
destination_server="@owlsnest.hpc.temple.edu"

read -p "Enter AccessNet ID: " destination_user
    
for sub in $(cat "${scriptdir}/sublist_new-flip.txt"); do

    source_fmriprep="$fmriprep_dir/sub-$sub"
    source_bids="$bids_dir/sub-$sub/func"

    # Transfer Preproc BOLD files and Confound files
    rsync -avh --no-compress --progress \
        --ignore-existing \
        --recursive \
        --include='*/' \
        --include='*MNI152NLin6Asym_desc-preproc_bold.nii.gz' \
        --include='*-confounds_timeseries.tsv' \
        --exclude='*' \
        "${source_fmriprep}" "${destination_user}${destination_server}:work/rf1-sra-data/derivatives/fmriprep/sub-${sub}/"

    # Transfer events.tsv files
    rsync -avh --no-compress --progress \
        --ignore-existing \
        --recursive \
        --include='*/' \
        --include='*_events.tsv' \
        --exclude='*' \
        "${source_bids}" "${destination_user}${destination_server}:work/rf1-sra-data/bids/sub-${sub}/"
    sleep 10
done

exit
```

I have troubleshot with the following methods and results:

Commenting out the second rsync command and keeping the sleep 10 delay allows the script to complete without receiving the errors. Conversely, commenting out the first rsync command does not have the same effect, and the script errors out when just trying to run the second rsync command, even with the delay.

Increasing the delay to 30 seconds for the second rsync fixes the problem, but makes this script take much longer than it theoretically should.

Deleting the current SSH key that prevents me from having to enter my password after every run of the for loop also seems to allow the first rsync command to run, but I suspect this just has a similar effect to delay.

I ran a similar script I have for a use case nearly identical to this with no issues at all. This script transfers much more information, but only runs the rsync command once every 30 seconds or so. This also supports the idea that there is a limit to how many commands I can run via SSH and rsync in a given time period.


-- The script runs both commands successfully with a 10 second delay to the first command, and a 30 second delay, but this adds much more time than reasonable. I am curious to see if anyone knows a way to circumvent this. Basically a script that should take no longer than 5 minutes to run takes 20-30 minutes due to what I believe to be request limits.

It seems like the second ssh connection failed: ssh: connect to host owlsnest.hpc.temple.edu port 22: Connection refused. Try to add a sleep 10 before the second rsync
